# Pansharpening of Landsat 8

Tags: remote-sensing, satellites

If I have a four band Landsat 8 image (Blue, Green, Red and NIR) and pansharpen this image using the panchromatic band. How accurate would the pansharpening be for the Blue and NIR bands? See band designations in attached image.

I would appreciate incites in this matter and also if I could find published literature on this subject.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pan-sharpen Landsat imagery, there is a surprisingly large amount of information accessible simply by completing an internet search.  Here is a source from the [NASA Earth Observatory](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/blogs/earthmatters/2017/06/13/how-to-pan-sharpen-landsat-imagery/) regarding exactly the question about how to pan-sharpen Landsat imagery, specifically Landsat 7 and 8.  They make specific comments about band sensitivities and differences between the sensors on Landsat 7 and 8.  Perhaps the provided source is a jumping off place to begin your work.

Comment: This answer could be improved by provide details from the site referenced.

Comment: As @Fred mentions, please include the main summary of the NASA answer in your answer